# Working Google Spreadsheet update Example

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I have been looking for a working example for updating a google spreadsheet.

Find my code below.

```
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


# write imports
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1ZaDwxCNxRzsV-OqaoeNvu-kDF3golHUMGh1FH11EVZ0'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'A1:B2'


def update_values(spreadsheet_id, range_name, value_input_option,
                  _values):
    """
    Creates the batch_update the user has access to.
    Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
    TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
    for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
        """
    #creds, _ = google.auth.default()
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
    try:

        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
        values = [
            [
                # Cell values ...
            ],
            # Additional rows ...
        ]
        body = {
            'values': values
        }
        result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name,
            valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=body).execute()
        print(f"{result.get('updatedCells')} cells updated.")

        return result
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_values(SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME, 'USER_ENTERED',
                  [
                      ['A', 'B'],
                      ['C', 'D'],
                  ])
```

I was getting output **None cells updated** on terminal when I run this. I have confirmed the range and values are correct but still not getting it. it gets little bit tricky to understand it from the docs as none working examples are provided for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1ZaDwxCNxRzsV-OqaoeNvu-kDF3golHUMGh1FH11EVZ0'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'A1:D3'


def update_values(spreadsheet_id, range_name, value_input_option, _values):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())

        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
        values = _values  # Use the provided values parameter
        body = {
            'values': values
        }
        result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name,
            valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=body).execute()
        print(f"{result.get('updatedCells')} cells updated.")
        return result
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_values(SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME, 'USER_ENTERED',
                  [
                      ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                      ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
                      ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']
                  ])
```

**also keep one thing in mind if you change scope then you'll have to delete token.json so it can be regenerated with updated scope**

*In above example that is not necessary as I'm updating it in code itself*